# Created /etc/nologin

Tags: nologin

I added `/etc/nologin` and now of course I can't login as a regular user or even as root.

It's a remote server which I can't physically get to. I receive the following msg when I use `ssh root@server`

```
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password)
```

CentOS Linux release 7.7.1908 (Core)

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Login in rescue mode and remove the file

Comment: root should still be able to log in at the console. What error do you get from a root login attempt?

Comment: It's a remote server which I can't physically get to. I receive the following msg when I use 'ssh root@server' -  Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).

Comment: Permission denied is because you haven't set up root (or ssh) to allow remote logins

Comment: Have the remote site restore from the latest backup before you created `/etc/nologin`; or start over, completely.

Comment: Physical servers have management processors like iLO or DRAC that allow you reboot and access the console via the network. Console access is also common for virtual servers. What kind or brand of server is this?

Comment: Worst case, find someone at the remote site who you trust (even a little). Talk then through logging in to the console as root and removing the `nologin`. Then you remotely login, change the root password, and reboot the system immediately

Comment: A reboot should delete /etc/nologin on Centos7.